# how to create a classification table using c++

Tags: c++

I was just wondering how it is possible to create a classification table using arrays. So I started the code below and I am stuck on how to replace numbers that are in a set range and make it equal to something else. I went it further detail of what I mean; by commenting in my code. I hope someone will be able to give me direction on this.

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
    vector<vector<double>> arrays = {
        { 0.2746458, 0.484255, 0.15154546, 0.0325468},
        { 0.141573001, 0.129732453, 0.3524564, 0.000458475} 
    };

size_t count = 0;
double sum = 0;
float element = 0; 
for (const vector<double> &array : arrays) {
    for (float element : array) {
        if (0.0 <= element && element <= 0.24) {
            /* This part of the code should replace any number within the given range 
            of 0.0 to 0.24 and make that number equal to 1 So essentially I want 
            the above array to end up looking like this:

            { 0.2746458, 0.484255, 1, 1},
            { 1, 1, 0.3524564, 1}
            */
        }
        if (0.24 <= element && element <= 0.5) {
            /*  This part of the code is meant to do something similar to the above one
            were it finds any number within a range of 0.24 to 0.5 and make each of those 
            numbers equal to 2 so the array ends up looking like this

            { 2, 2, 1, 1},
            { 1, 1, 2, 1}
            */
        }
    }
}

cout << "Classification Table " << endl;
//print the arrays after it has gone through the above code


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Definitely not [tag:c] code, removed the tag.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to store values changing depending from the initial value ? Or store only classes (ie `int` or even `enum`) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy class. For example:

```
class DynamicValue
{
  private:
    int c;
  public:
    DynamicValue() : c(0) {}
    DynamicValue(double x) : c() { this->c = this->classification(x); }
    DynamicValue(const DynamicValue& dv) c(dv.c) {}
    ~DynamicValue() {}
    DynamicValue& operator = (double x) {
      this->c = this->classification(x);
      return *this;
    }
    DynamicValue& operator = (const DynamicValue& dv) {
      this->c = dv.c;
      return *this;
    }
    operator int () { return this->c; }
    int classification(double x) {
      if(x < 0.0) return 0;
      else if(x < 0.24) return 1;
      else if(x < 0.5) return 2;
      else return 3;
    }
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
std::vector<DynamicValue> values(5);
values[0] = 0.3;
values[1] = -0.01;
values[2] = 0.1;
values[3] = 0.63;
values[4] = 0.21;
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
  std::cout << (int)values[i] << std::endl; // will print 20131
```

Comment: but will it be able to read the arrays that I left in the code ? and print out the array in the order of {2, 2, 1, 1}?? or do I have to manually put the numbers individually like values[0] = 0.2746, values[1] = 0.484255 etc.

Comment: Why do you want to initialize it by hand ? I suppose your data come from something your read, and you fill it with a loop ?

Comment: I dont want to intialize it by hand. I just want it to read the arrays that are in the starter code that i wrote and i desire the code to recognise the numbers in the array and create a new array that follows the entire "if 0<x<0.24 then return 1;". So what im technically asking is can the code be made to read the arrays and make a new set of arrays to print out?

Comment: Then, data are known at compile time. Why do not encode directly the classes ?

Comment: the truth is I dont know how to because I am new to c++, also i tried running the code on visual studio and its not working. It's saying things like class"dynamicvalue" has no member "classification" and 8 other errors